# Sorting dictionary by the closest value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary of the keys and values, that values are from 0.0 to 1.0 like this the one below:

```
{'item1': 0.88, 'item2': 0.4, 'item3': 0.49, 'item4': 0.75, 'item5': 0.32, 'item6': 0.9}
```

I had to sort it by the value closest to `0.5`.
I know how to sort dictionary ascending or descending from the greatest or the lowest value, by using:

```
sorted_by_value = sorted(dic.items(), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

But I'm clueless when it comes to sorting form the closest value to given one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, just do:

```
d = {'item1': 0.88, 'item2': 0.4, 'item3': 0.49, 'item4': 0.75, 'item5': 0.32, 'item6': 0.9}

sorted_by_value = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: abs(x[1] - 0.5))

print(sorted_by_value)
```

**Output**

```
[('item3', 0.49), ('item2', 0.4), ('item5', 0.32), ('item4', 0.75), ('item1', 0.88), ('item6', 0.9)]
```